# Convert string to variable, possible?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I have 4 variables containing 4 different strings. I want to use a for-loop for the creating of a table, and apply the strings into the cells. With my code below i get "content1", "content2" and so on as strings, instead of the strings in the variables content1, content2 and so on. Is it possible to convert the strings that are created in the loop (eg. "content1") to the variables, if so how do I do?

```
var content1 = "Text1";
var content2 = "Text2";
var content3 = "Text3";
var content4 = "Text4";

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){        
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode("content" + [k]);
    td.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

table.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: I really doubt that this works at all. What is [k] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `window['content' + k]` instead, but also seriously consider changing your design so you DON'T need variable variables. They're a horrible monstrosity and lead to next-to-impossible-to-debug code.

At bare minimum, switch to using an array:

```
content = ['', 'Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4']; // empty string to fill in the '0' element

alert(content[1]); // outputs Text1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var content = ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"];

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){        
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode( content[i] );
    td.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

table.appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you could use and array to hold your strings:

```
var content = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4'];
```

And later

```
var text = document.createTextNode(content[i+1]);
```

Another very not recommended option is to evaluate the code:

```
eval("var text = content" + (i+1));
var text = document.createTextNode(text);
```

This will work but has risks, and is flaky in general.

Answer (score 0):

Creating content as an array should work.

```
var content = new Array();

content[0] = "Text1";
content[1] = "Text2";
content[2] = "Text3";

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){        
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode("content" + content[k]);
    td.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

table.appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework here is some food for though:

Put all your variables in a "content" array :

```
var content = new Array("Text1", "Text2" ...);
```

Then iterate through it and access it like `content[i]`

```
for (var i = 0; i < content .length; i++){...}
```

Hope it helps :)